# Script throwing random EOF line error in bash task

Tags: linux, shell, devops

**My script is below , and it is showing the EOF line error randomly.**

```
set -x
unset -f arrayKeys
unset -f arrayValues
unset -f key
unset -f value
kubectl -n $(projectId) create secret generic $(subscriptionId)-secret
arrayValues=($(echo $(array)| tr " ," " "))
arrayKeys=($(echo $(arrayKey)| tr " ," " "))
for i in ${!arrayValues[@]}; do  
    echo $i
    key=$(echo -n ${arrayKeys[$i]})
    value=$(echo -n ${arrayValues[$i]})
    kubectl -n $(projectId) patch secret $(subscriptionId)-secret -p '{"data":{"'"$(echo -n $key)"'":"'"$(echo -n "$value" | tr -d '\n')"'"}}'
done
```

**Error**
line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I am not sure , what is causing the error .

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net (include `#!/bin/bash` or whatever shell you are using as the first line). Fix any flagged issues and retest. If that doesn't solve it, update your posting with imporved code AND the `set -x` output from just before when the error message is generated. Good luck.

Comment: what do you think `tr " ," " "` does?

Comment: why do you use `var=$(echo -n ${arr[$k]})` and not `var=${arr[$k]}` ?

Comment: check that your file does not contain DOS line endings and that all the double-quotes are actually double-quotes, not smart-quotes

Comment: `$( ... )` is not the same thing as `${ ... }`

Comment: Try to find a smallest reproducible example, for instance by replacing `kubectl` by `printf "%s "`, and then remove parts of the line piece by piece, until you have found the culprit. Your quoting looks weird. Also, if you **really** posted the error message verbatim, it could indicate that you have carriage return characters in your script.